# ASUS F1A75-M motherboard - where is PXE boot in AMI BIOS 2.00, 2012?

Tags: motherboard, bios, pxe

I'm re-purposing a legacy computer, a short under-desk box with F1A75-M motherboard. I found the instructions on-line, I've been through every line in American Megatrends, Inc BIOS 2.00, version 2012.

I found specific instructions on enabling the network stack, in section 5 of the Advanced menu, but there is nothing remotely like "network", "stack", "XE", "EFI" or any other constituent part of a name for this feature, in this copy of the BIOS. Nada. Zippo. Would AMI upgrade the BIOS without updating the revision number? Do I need to jumper the motherboard? Connect to an active network? Its a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mention of a PXE bootroom at all in [the manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketFM1/F1A75-M/E6658_F1A75-M.zip).

Since PXE is optional this makes it very likely that it simply is not an option for this motherboard build in equipment.  If you really wish you could add a dedicated NIC with its own ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Hennes, I think you've got it right. There is no PXE boot on this old board. I just updated the BIOS to "2403" the up-to-date version for plain "F1A75-M", no suffix. Build date: 05/26/2014. I doubt it will change.
Fini.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual posted above, it should be the (ill) named: *Atheros* [option] *ROM*.

If it can also be of help then, if when starting it you get E61 errors (as if the cable wasn't there, but it is) try power cycling the system. I spent a hour banging my head for this with the built-in Attansic NIC of my old ASUS board.